# Python RegEx - unintended full-stop match

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to write a Python regex pizza matching quite a few different date formats, and I have encountered an error I cannot really explain. My current regex pattern looks like so:

```
r'((?:\d?\d[-/ ])?(?:\d?\d|(?:(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z]*))(?:(?:\d?\d)?[,-/ ])\d{2,4})'
```

It works great for almost everything in my data set, but e.g. this string remains defiant:

```
'Lithium 0.25 (7/11/77).  LFTS wnl.  Urine tox neg.  Serum tox + fluoxetine 500; otherwise neg.  TSH 3.28.  BUN/Cr: 16/0.83.  Lipids unremarkable.  B12 363, Folate >20.  CBC: 4.9/36/308 Pertinent Medical Review of Systems Constitutional:\n'
```

My pattern persistently matches **0.25** in it, right in front of the date. For the life of me, I do not understand what causes that full-stop to be matched, as I am quite precise in what I want it to capture. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Cheers,
Greem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is `,-/` in `[,-/ ]`because it matches chars from `,` to `/`. Use `[-,/ ]` instead.

[image]

Comment: Holy cow, a good find! Very tricky detail - I would probably spend ages looking at that square bracket before it would occur to me that the '-' in there with special symbols around will get interpreted as "from that to this hec address". Thanks mate!